# How to create user for connect to database

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu

```
ERROR :
[FATAL] [DBT-05509] Failed to connect to the specified database (cdb21).
   CAUSE: OS Authentication might be disabled for this database (cdb21).
   ACTION: Specify a valid sysdba user name and password to connect to the database.
```

First step:

```
./runInstaller -silent -responseFile /scratch/app/user/product/21.0.0/dbhome_1/install/response/db_install.rsp \
oracle.install.option=INSTALL_DB_SWONLY \
UNIX_GROUP_NAME=oinstall \
ORACLE_BASE=/scratch/app/user \
INVENTORY_LOCATION=/scratch/app/oraInventory  \
SELECTED_LANGUAGES=en \
oracle.install.db.InstallEdition=EE \
oracle.install.db.isCustomInstall=false \
oracle.install.db.OSDBA_GROUP=oinstall \
oracle.install.db.OSBACKUPDBA_GROUP=oinstall \
oracle.install.db.OSDGDBA_GROUP=oinstall \
oracle.install.db.OSKMDBA_GROUP=oinstall \
oracle.install.db.OSRACDBA_GROUP=oinstall \
SECURITY_UPDATES_VIA_MYORACLESUPPORT=false \
DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES=true
```

Second step:

```
dbca -silent -createDatabase                     \
-templateName General_Purpose.dbc                \
-gdbname cdb21                                   \
-sid cdb21                                       \
-responseFile NO_VALUE                           \
-characterSet AL32UTF8                           \
-sysPassword Welcome1                            \
-systemPassword Welcome1                         \
-createAsContainerDatabase true                  \
-numberOfPDBs 1                                  \
-pdbName pdb21                                   \
-pdbAdminPassword Welcome1                       \
-databaseType MULTIPURPOSE                       \
-memoryMgmtType auto_sga                         \
-totalMemory 4096                                \
-storageType FS                                  \
-datafileDestination /scratch/oradata/           \
-emConfiguration NONE                            \
-ignorePreReqs
```

Comment: Ok, so you show the scripts you used to install oracle and create a database.  But you did not show the command that actually produced the error.  And you have tagged this question with 'Ubuntu'.  Ubuntu from an entirely different branch of the liinux family tree than that for which oracle was designed.  Ubuntu is _NOT_ listed as a valid os in the oracle installation guide for linux. Even if you manage to get it installed (using hacks you find on the internet) there is zero confidence that any particular action will actually work.  ( to be continued . . . )

Comment: ( . . . continued).  If, as it appears, you are trying to set up a database on your personal machine that is running Ubuntu, do what I did on _my_ Ubuntu laptop:  Install Oracle Virtual Box.  Use that to create a VM that runs Oracle Linux, and install your db there.  Give that VM a 'hostonly' network adapter with a fixed IP address, and you can treat that VM just like a server that lives behind a locked door in a lights-out data center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start The service using :

```
lsnrctl start
```

Then :

```
startup
```

Answer (score 0):

From your formulation it's not clear if you encountered the error during the creation of the database or afterwards.
But I'm ASSUMING you're encountering the error during the second step that created your pdb. I have used your script to create a database and it succeeded without errors on a RHEL 8 machine.
According to one article on Oracle knowledge, this could be do to incorrect value in ORA_NLS10. In this scenario, you should fix the variable of ORA_NLS10 or since ORA_NLS10 is not required for db creation at least since version 19, unset ORA_NLS10.